# Stream_flush in not being called while using stream wrapper

Tags: 7, stream-wrappers

I've created a stream wrapper foo:// and when I am using this wrapper and my file moved successfully but the flush_stream function is not called I don't why I also checked for the public:// stream wrapper and It calls the flush_stream function after moving file.

I backtracked the code while running for public:// stream wrapper I got this output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [function] => stream_flush
        [class] => DrupalLocalStreamWrapper
        [object] => DrupalPublicStreamWrapper Object
            (
                [context] => 
                [handle] => Resource id #11
                [uri:protected] => public://a1a1211127_aa_0.jpg
            )

        [type] => ->
        [args] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [file] => /var/www/html/includes/file.inc
        [line] => 1633
        [function] => move_uploaded_file
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => /tmp/phpPaIdAn
                [1] => public://a1a1211127_aa_0.jpg
            )

    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [file] => /var/www/html/includes/file.inc
        [line] => 1585
        [function] => drupal_move_uploaded_file
        [args] => Array
            (
                [0] => /tmp/phpPaIdAn
                [1] => public://a1a1211127_aa_0.jpg
            )

    )
```

It means stream_flush is called after the move_uploaded_file function. But in my case the move_uploaded_file function is called but stream_flush is not.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just changed the stream wrapper type to STREAM_WRAPPERS_LOCAL_NORMAL and implements the chmod function and it works seamlessly.